# why node.js upgrade version 0.12.x directly to 4.0.0?

Tags: node.js, version

I guess there maybe some reasons with io.js, but I don't know the history.

Could someone explain this history:

1. What's the relationship between node.js and io.js?
2. why node.js doesn't have version 1, 2, but directly release version 4.0.0?

Comment: Fully answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468832/now-that-node-js-has-added-io-js-is-it-more-async-than-it-was-before-whats-wi/32469085#32469085

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. io.js *was* a fork of node.js. The two projects converged recently.
2. This discrepancy is explained in many different places on the web, including on the nodejs.org in the news section [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/foundation-v4-announce/). Specifically this part of the announcement:

   > Named version 4.0.0 because it includes major updates from io.js version 3.0.0